# How can I prove that a program is memory bound?

Tags: performance, performance-testing

As far as I can tell, there are three general ways to describe the limitations on the running time of a program: CPU bound, memory bound, and I/O bound.  How can I prove that a program is memory bound?

Comment: Remove all the computation, and observe that the run-time doesn't change?

Comment: Odd how profilers remain mysterious tools only whispered about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean "prove", as in an academic exercise, or "prove", as in justify buying more memory for the system it runs on?

In the first case, you'd need a lot of detail about what the algorithm is doing, and what the memory latency looks like. If you can show that the cache miss frequency * main memory latency is >= the number of "productive" computation cycles, then the program is memory-bound.

To make a case that an existing piece of software is *probably* memory-bound, you can use a low-level profiler to get the same kind of information (cache-miss frequency, etc). Or you could try running the program with the CPU either clocked down to a lower rate, or occupied with other work, and see if the runtime increases linearly with CPU degradation, or somewhat more slowly.